# How to solve "KeyError: 'cpu'" error when trying to generate configFileName.xml with Gem5toMcpat?

Tags: python, gem5

Hello I am trying to generate configFileName.xml by using the following command in Gem5toMcpat parser which is installed on ubuntu 20

```
 python Program.py stats.txt  config.json  ARM_A9_2GHz.xml
```

but it showed me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Program.py", line 964, in <module>
    main()
  File "Program.py", line 38, in main
    countCores(sys.argv[2])
  File "Program.py", line 70, in countCores
    noCores = len(configfile["system"]["cpu"])
KeyError: 'cpu'
```

Comment: Show `Program.py` code, so others can help

Comment: it is in this link https://github.com/Hardik44/Gem5toMcPat_parser

Comment: As you see https://github.com/Hardik44/Gem5toMcPat_parser/issues/2 there is an issue in the guthub repo

Comment: Is this problem has a solution ?

Comment: Well @John, everyproblem does. But I can't simply edit the source code of a whole repo, for it will take a lot of time and energy. Contact the repo administrators bro